# Hotspot shield on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hotspot-shield

I am using ***Hotspot shield version 7.4.2***, and I can turn it on with this command on windows cmd:

```
cd '.\Program Files (x86)\Hotspot Shield\bin\'
.\hsscp.exe -connect
```

how can i **disconnect** it using command line?

Comment: Have you tried “-disconnect”?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, -disconnect doesn't work

Comment: What documentation did you learn about -connect?

Comment: @Ramhound in the previous versions there were no need to "-connect", but after updating to version 7 it needs to write -connect at the end of the command. I tested it, but I couldn't find a command for disconnecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for reset IP try

> taskkill /f /im hydra.exe

for disconect only

> taskkill /f /im hsscp.exe

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread, but this could be useful to someone.
It's a horrible (outdated) hack using powershell and relies on sending a keyboard shortcut (look under hotspot shield's settings -> shortcuts).

```
# Powershell
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
# This will bring window to the front, (will not open multiple instances of the exe)
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Hotspot Shield\10.22.5\bin\hsscp.exe" 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1   # for the window to show
# Activate the Hotspot Shield window to make sure send keys 'hits' the right window
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Hotspot Shield")
# Send ctrl+shift+c to toggle between connect and disconnect
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^+c")
# Wait for it to connect/disconnect
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
# Your adapter may have a different name just use Get-NetAdapter for a list of all adapters
Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription "HotspotShield TAP-Windows Adapter V9" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Status
#
```

Note:- takes a while to connect hence the 5 second wait before checking status - disconnect is quicker.

Does anyone know why 'hsscp  start' and 'hsscp  stop' does not work?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).